# PHP version 7 if I add the GROUP BY I get the error?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Everything works ok, but if I add GROUP BY messagesuserone to ORDER BY  messagedate DESC, I get error `Trying to get property of non-object in ...`. Where am I wrong?...., Can you correct the code, to see how it looks ... Please, I need this, I'm scrambling all day .. 
Please, without too much description, my English is not the best. Thx.

PHP version: 7

Tables:

**users**

userID, email, password, firstname, lastname, avatar

**users_residence**

users_residenceID, userresidenceID, state, city

**users_messages**

messagesID, messagesuseroneID, messagesusertwoID, message, messagedate, messageread

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
$user = $_SESSION['userID'];

$sql = "SELECT messagesusertwoID, messagesuseroneID, messagedate,
messageread, SUM(messageread) AS messageread_sum, 
userID, firstname, lastname, avatar, state, city  FROM users_messages 
LEFT JOIN users ON userID = messagesuseroneID 
LEFT JOIN users_residence ON userresidenceID = messagesuseroneID 
WHERE messagesusertwoID = '$user' 
GROUP BY messagesuseroneID ORDER BY messagedate DESC ";
                 $result = $con->query($sql);

                 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                 // output data of each row
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                     {

                     echo   ''.$row["avatar"].'
                             '.$row["userID"].'
                             '.$row["firstname"].'
                             '.$row["lastname"].'
                             '.$row["state"].'
                             '.$row["city"].'
                             '.$row["messageread_sum"].'';

                 }
                 } else {
                 echo "0 results";
                 }
                 }
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed the code that *didn't* work

Comment: Umm...... what GROUP BY? and what's the error? we're not mindreaders you know.

Comment: `ORDER BY MAX(date)`? How do you order something by the maximum value of a column or a date? Where does `date` even come from?

Comment: PHP is not guilty. Because of the `GROUP BY` the query becomes invalid SQL and `$con->query($sql)` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: messagesusertwo to - What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: You shouldn't leave the question or ignore comments. I for one have left it; least I said so.

Comment: Ok i corrected and added but again the same ????

Comment: @aldin_abdagic: You added what to where? I don't understand.

Comment: **Your question is still missing the desired output.** Without that your question is off topic and an answer that suggest the necessary code changes is not possible or speculative.

Comment: In order to get a helpful answer improve the quality of the question: remove the PHP code (it is just noise for this question), format the query to be readable without scrolling, post the structure of the tables (what fields belong to each table) and, the most important part, explain what do you expect this query to return.

Comment: If you want to help ..., Okay, but now I'm left without time. Can I send private messages on stackoverflies, to contact you. I do not know how exactly that stackoverflov works?

Comment: There are no private messages on [so] but there are chat rooms used to avoid polluting the questions with long discussions. However, it's better to put the relevant information in the question; many people read the question and the chances to get an answer increase. Just use the [edit] button under the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All expressions that appear in the `SELECT` clause that are not calls to [`GROUP BY` aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) must either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be functionally dependent on expressions that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Otherwise the `GROUP BY` query is invalid SQL.

Before version 5.7.5, MySQL used to accept invalid `GROUP BY` queries but it reserved its right to [return indeterminate data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). This means such an invalid query may return different results when it runs against different database instances that contain the same data (e.g. your database now vs. your database moved to a different server or restored from a backup).

Because the SQL query is invalid, [`$con->query($sql)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) [returns `FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues) and the next statement (`$result->num_rows`) triggers the error.

Comment: Before to version 5.7.5, everything was working normal, but now it say; Try to get propertj of non-object in. What to change in the code ??

Comment: @aldin_abdagic Your question is basically `Where am I wrong?`. This answer answers it perfectly :-) If you want a code change suggestion modify your question, so that your desired output gets clear. Otherwise this lion's answer deserves to be *accepted*.

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a solution without knowing the tables structure. Also, you didn't mention in the question what is the query expected to return.

Comment: Can you correct the code, to see how it looks ... Please, I need this, I'm scrambling all day ..